# Mapinfo + Java : A way to decrypt coordinates in a DAT file?

Tags: java, google-maps, encryption, mapinfo

I have .DAT files representing lines in the map. The .dat file I can easily visualize in MapInfo. 
The x,y,z positions of the lines are stored in columns in that .DAT file with the Lambert 2 coordinates system.
These coordinates seem to be encrypted by MapInfo.
Is there a way to decrypt them using Java.
What I already used, is to convert these .dat file to shp file using MapInfo tool and then loading them in Geoserver which was able to display the geographic data.

Comment: Could you specify more clearly what the input looks like and what output you want to have?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found this:

> The MapInfo dataset format, which comprises a group of related files,
>   is developed and regulated as a proprietary GIS dataset format used in
>   MapInfo products. **MapInfo's component .DAT file is a dBASE Table File**
>   in dBase (III, IV, or V) format which is well documented. As of August
>   2011, the MapInfo products are maintained and distributed by Pitney
>   Bowes Business Insight.

source: http://www.digitalpreservation.gov/formats/fdd/fdd000324.shtml

You can probably read that file using this library: http://dans-dbf-lib.sourceforge.net/

Alternatively, if you want to read your converted shape files with java, GeoTools is a pretty good library for doing it:  http://www.geotools.org/  The tutorial contains examples of reading shape files.

Comment: I read .dat file but I need to read .MAP file also, How can I do that ?